# Pandas Pivot Table to One_hot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I want to convert a pandas df into a One_hot pandas df.
The best way to describe might be with an example:

The df I have looks like this:

```
ID|DEV |STATE|
1 |DEV1|on
2 |DEV2|on
3 |DEV1|off
3 |DEV3|on
3 |DEV3|off
```

I know the not unique id isn't nice and I am working on it.

Then I pivot the table:

```
data.pivot_table(index='ID', columns=['DEV'], values='STATE', dropna=True, aggfunc='first')
```

Which results in the following

```
ID|DEV1|DEV2|DEV3
1 |on  | NaN| NaN
2 | NaN| on | NaN
3 | off| NaN| on
4 | NaN| NaN| off
```

And I would now like to get something like this:

```
ID|DEV1.on|DEV1.off|DEV2.on|DEV3.on|DEV3.off
1 |     1 |       0|      0|      0|       0
2 |     0 |       0|      1|      0|       0
3 |     0 |       1|      0|      1|       0
4 |     0 |       0|      0|      0|       1
```

I know how to join the column names but I do not know how to get the "one-hot"-Style. Maybe it is possible with an aggfunc?

Can you help me?

Fabian

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) with joined columns with separator `.`, index by `ID` column by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and last get `max` per indices:

```
df['join'] = df['DEV'] + '.' + df['STATE']
df = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('ID')['join']).max(level=0)
print (df)
    DEV1.off  DEV1.on  DEV2.on  DEV3.off  DEV3.on
ID                                               
1          0        1        0         0        0
2          0        0        1         0        0
3          1        0        0         1        1
```

Another solution with `MultiIndex` and reshaping by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) - but then is necessary [`swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html), [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and last flatten `MultiIndex`:

```
df = (pd.get_dummies(df.set_index(['ID','DEV'])['STATE'])
        .max(level=[0,1])
        .unstack(fill_value=0)
        .swaplevel(0,1, axis=1)
        .sort_index(axis=1))

df.columns = df.columns.map('.'.join)
print (df)
    DEV1.off  DEV1.on  DEV2.off  DEV2.on  DEV3.off  DEV3.on
ID                                                         
1          0        1         0        0         0        0
2          0        0         0        1         0        0
3          1        0         0        0         1        1
```

Comment: Thank you very much! s there a way to use `pd.get_dummies` and have NaN instead of 0 ?

Comment: @FabianZills - Last add `df = df.mask(df == 0)`

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
df['new_col'] = df['DEV'] + '.' + df['STATE']
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df['new_col'])
df = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1).drop(['DEV', 'STATE','new_col'], axis=1)
df = df.groupby("ID").sum().replace(0, np.nan)
```

Output:

```
    DEV1.off  DEV1.on  DEV2.on  DEV3.off  DEV3.on
ID                                               
1        NaN      1.0      NaN       NaN      NaN
2        NaN      NaN      1.0       NaN      NaN
3        1.0      NaN      NaN       1.0      1.0
```